# Python and fortran with ctypes: lists with objects

Tags: python, dll, fortran, ctypes

I need to write a library in fortran that will take an array of objects from Python, process it and return it back.

I've tried a lot of options, the last one looks like this:

Code Python:

```
import ctypes as ct
import os
import numpy as np

here = os.path.dirname(__file__)
lib_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(here, '..', 'fortran', 'svector_test_mod.dll'))
fortlib = ct.CDLL(lib_file, winmode=0)


class StateVector(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ct.c_longdouble),
        ('y', ct.c_longdouble),
        ('z', ct.c_longdouble),
        ('vx', ct.c_longdouble),
        ('vy', ct.c_longdouble),
        ('vz', ct.c_longdouble),
        ('t', ct.c_longdouble),
    ]


size = 5
array = (StateVector * size)()

for i in range(size):
    array[i].x = ct.c_longdouble(2.5)
    array[i].y = ct.c_longdouble(2.5)
    array[i].z = ct.c_longdouble(2.5)
    array[i].vx = ct.c_longdouble(2.5)
    array[i].vy = ct.c_longdouble(2.5)
    array[i].vz = ct.c_longdouble(2.5)
    array[i].t = ct.c_longdouble(2.5)


np_objects = np.ctypeslib.as_array(array)

arr_ptr = np_objects.ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(ct.c_void_p))

fortlib.lists_change(ct.byref(arr_ptr), size)
```

Code Fortran:

```
module state_vector_mod
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: C_LONG_DOUBLE, c_int, C_PTR, C_F_POINTER
    implicit none

    type, bind(C) :: state_vector
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE) :: x
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE) :: y
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE) :: z
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE) :: vx
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE) :: vy
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE) :: vz
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE) :: t
    end type state_vector

    contains

    subroutine make_sv(x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, t, sv) bind(c, name='make_sv')
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: x
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: y
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: z
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: vx
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: vy
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: vz
        real(C_LONG_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: t
        type(state_vector), intent(out), target :: sv

        sv = state_vector(x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, t)
    end subroutine make_sv

    subroutine lists_change(in_list, length) bind(C, name='lists_change')
        type(C_PTR), intent(inout) :: in_list
        !type(state_vector), dimension(length), intent(out) :: out_list
        type(state_vector), dimension(:), pointer :: my_array
        integer(c_int), intent(in) :: length
        integer(c_int) :: i

        call C_F_POINTER(in_list, my_array, [length])

        DO i = 1, length
            my_array(i)%x = my_array(i)%x * 2
            my_array(i)%y = my_array(i)%y * 2
            my_array(i)%z = my_array(i)%z * 2
            my_array(i)%vx = my_array(i)%vx * 2
            my_array(i)%vy = my_array(i)%vy * 2
            my_array(i)%vz = my_array(i)%vz * 2
            my_array(i)%t = my_array(i)%t * 2
        END DO

        !out_list = my_array
        deallocate(my_array)
    end subroutine lists_change
end module state_vector_mod
```

But when I call the `lists_change` function, an error appears "OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000005"

Please tell me how you can fix it and whether the code is written correctly in general?

Comment: Why is `in_list` `intent(inout)`? It isn't being modified, and possibly should even be `value`?

Comment: @francescalus yes, thank you, perhaps you are right, but unfortunately this does not solve the problem with the error when starting Python.


PS: I'm sorry if my fortran code is bad, I'm new to it

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. You can also read [ask] and [mcve] for some tips. The address in the error message is peculiar. As if an integer value is interpreted as an address in a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The address in the error message is peculiar. It points to an integer value of 5 being used as an address value. The variable `size` has this value. We can conclude that the argument `length`

```
    integer(c_int), intent(in) :: length
```

should actually have the `value` attribute

```
    integer(c_int), value :: length
```

or that it should be called from Python by reference (`ct.byref`).

Regarding general points, francescalus is right that the `in_list` array pointer is modified and should likely be passed as value so you can get rid of the `ct.byref` or with `intent(in)`. Or you can also just pass the array itself by reference and avoid casting de-referencing the pointer.

```
    type(state_vector), intent(inout) :: my_array(length)
```

or with some obvious modifications if you introduce a separate `out_list` argument that is now commented out.